# Show right angles for orthogonal vectors in 3D

Tags: vectors, 3d, orthogonality

This question is one of simple computational geometry, similar to what I posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186711/rgl-vector-diagrams-show-right-angles-for-orthogonal-vectors. But no one answered, so I thought I would ask here.

Given: 2 orthogonal vectors in 3D, how to draw the right angle `|_` symbol at their intersection?

The problem reduces to the following:  Given three points, `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, find the points labeled `p21`, `p23`, and `p123` in the diagram below.  The first two are simple examples of finding a point along a line between two points, but I'm stumped on finding the coordinates of the third point, `p123`, that is the position of a point a distance `d` along a line parallel to the line `p2->p3` starting at `p21`.

[image: vector3d-diagram]

For example, with the points below,

```
p1 <- c(0,0,0)
p2 <- c(1,1,0)
p3 <- c(1,1,1)
```

the following diagram marks the points `p21` and `p23` in red. How do I find what I called `p123`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point $p_{123}$ is the sum $p_2+(p_{23}-p_2)+(p_{21}-p_2)$, that is:
$$
p_{123}=dp_{3}+dp_{1}+(1-2d)p_2.
$$
Example: if $p_2=(1,1,0)$, $p_{1}=(0,0,0)$ and $p_3=(1,1,1)$, then
$p_{123}=(1-d,1-d,d)$.